# How to open numerous folders and replace all the files contents using batch files

Tags: batch-file

I am new to writing batch files.Can anyone tell me how to open all the folders from root folder and open all the files in it and change their content. Means if "C:\abc\xyz" now all the files in 'abc' folder should get their contents changed and then all the files in 'xyz' folder. Now I do have code for changing file contents. Kindly tell me how to get into folders and sub folders and get all the files changed ...

CODE TO REPLACE STRING IN FILES

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=b.txt
set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=path
set REPLACETEXT=hello
set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
SET string=%%A
SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

---

With following code I do get all files in D:

@echo off
IF EXIST D:\*.* goto process
echo does not exist

:process
for %%a in (D:\*.*) do echo %%a

AND with by appling '/d' I do get all folders

for /d %%a in (D:\
*.*) do echo %%a

However I am not able to use them together ...I want all files from all folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `HELP FOR`, then try `FOR /R %A IN (*.TXT) DO ECHO %A`

then modify your batch file accordingly, adding something like this

```
FOR /R %%A IN (*.TXT) DO (
  ECHO %%A
  FOR /F %%B in (%%A) DO (
     ECHO %%B
  )
)
```

Comment: With this code I do get all files in D: 

@echo off
IF EXIST D:\*.* goto process
echo does not exist

:process
for %%a in (D:\*.*) do echo %%a

AND with by appling '/d' I do get all folders

for /d %%a in (D:\*.*) do echo %%a

However I am not able to use them together ...I want all files from all folders

Comment: have you just tried `FOR /R %A IN (*.*) DO ECHO %A` **without** the `IF EXIST` check?

Comment: thank you for your help                                          @echo off
SET filLoc=C:\Users
FOR /r %filLoc% %%x IN (*.*) DO echo %%x